# Conditional wont be read in do while statement

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

For my program I am trying to have the loop run until the letter n is entered. But for some reason i keep receiving the error cannot find symbol in the condition for my loop. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog213c
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in); 

        do{
            System.out.println( "Enter student number");
            int studentNumber = kbReader.nextInt();
            System.out.println(" Enter credits ");
            int credits = kbReader.nextInt();

            switch (credits) 
            {
            case 30: 
                System.out.println("Grade Level code = 2");
                break;
            case 29: 
                System.out.println("Grade Level code = 1");
                break;
            case 70:
                System.out.println("Grade Level code = 3");
                break;
            case 103:
                System.out.println("Grade Level code = 4");
                break;

            default: System.out.println("invalid number");
            }
            System.out.print("Do again(y/n)");
            String answer = kbReader.next();
        } while (answer == 'y'); // error received here
```

Comment: The variable `answer` is declared inside the loop, meaning that it's not available in the condition (which is outside the loop). Move the declaration outside the loop. Probably this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scope of variable inside do-while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324653/scope-of-variable-inside-do-while-loop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

```
String answer = kbReader.next();
} while (answer == 'y'); // error received here
```

Technically, `answer` is out of scope when you try to use - you can only use `answer` inside the loop itself. You should declare `answer` prior to starting your `while` loop so that it's in scope. Also, `answer` is a string and you're trying to "directly" compare it to a `char`.

This is also performing a case-sensitive comparison; while this isn't technically incorrect, it would be more user-friendly to accept accept either "Y" or "y".

Also, your `switch` statement won't work correctly. For example, `case 30` will only be called if `credits` is *exactly* 30, which I assume isn't what you want.

You *could* do something like:

```
case 30:
case 31:
case 32: // ...
```

but that seems like a thoroughly painful way to do that. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/in-java-using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case) for more details.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19062152/4032703) is particularly interesting and could be useful for your purposes. This is the code from that answer:

```
switch ((int) num/10) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("10-19");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("20-29");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("30-39");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("40-49");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

(Again, just to give credit where credit's due the above isn't my code, it was from the linked answer).

Also:

```
int studentNumber = kbReader.nextInt();
```

You never actually do anything with `studentNumber`, just prompt the user for it. Did you mean to do this?

Comment: well the switch statement is another problem in general. I was told to use a switch statement even though an if else statement is the only way it could work. In terms of my problem with the conditionals thank you for the answer. I have fixed the problem and my program will now compile

Comment: Glad it helped. Out of curiosity, do you know why the assignment required a `switch` statement? That seems like a very odd requirement to me.

Comment: Also yes I meant to do that. My assignment asks for the students to enter their student number. But the number isnt needed for the output at all

Comment: It was required because it was one of the requirements by my teacher and is the lesson we are on. Just by reading the assignment description however, a switch statement seems pretty impossible.

Comment: I added a few ideas about that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Single quotes are character literals in Java. So you can't compare a
   String with a char directly.
2. Your answer variable has to be declared before the do-while loop.
3. you have to use the [equals method to compare strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).
   `answer.equals("y")`

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted - all of those are perfectly true.

Comment: Maybe because I didn't include the scope related problem the first time. Hope the downvoter review my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:
since `answer` is a string object, this is not working `(answer == 'y');`

you can do `"y".equals(answer)` is you get the nextLine from the scanner

or if you need to work with chars

```
char x = kbReader.next().charAt(0);
while (x == 'y');
```

Problem 2:

answer must be declared before the do-while loop...

your final code can look like

```
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    char answer = 'y';
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter student number");
        int studentNumber = kbReader.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" Enter credits ");
        int credits = kbReader.nextInt();

        switch (credits) {
        case 30:
            System.out.println("Grade Level code = 2");
            break;
        case 29:
            System.out.println("Grade Level code = 1");
            break;
        case 70:
            System.out.println("Grade Level code = 3");
            break;
        case 103:
            System.out.println("Grade Level code = 4");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("invalid number");
        }
        System.out.print("Do again(y/n)");
        answer = kbReader.next().charAt(0);
    } while (answer == 'y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your while condition to:

```
while ("y".equals(kbReader.next()));
```